# How to set: 2015-06-17 05:25:21 +0000 as a let NSDate constant

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm trying to set an `NSDate` constant:

```
let formattedDate: NSDate = 2015-06-17 05:25:21 +0000
```

but when I set it I get numerous errors:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to specified type 'NSDate'
>   Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

I'm unit testing so I need the `formattedDate: NSDate` to test against.

Comment: It's easier to get the Unix TimeStamp corresponding, and init the date from it.

Comment: Why are you using `NSDate` and not `Date`? And `Date` isn't formatted. What you are trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: @rmaddy I would still get the same errors if I do  let formattedDate: Date = 2015-06-17 05:25:21 +0000

Comment: @Larme not entirely sure the process you are referring to

Comment: "2015-06-17 05:25:21 +0000 " That's seems more to be the description of a Date. `let formattedDate: NSDate = 2015-06-17 05:25:21 +0000` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Of course since what you are trying to do makes no sense. But at least use the correct class.

Comment: is that a typo what you are showing here...? because that is not a valid code on so many levels.

Comment: It's equivalent to `1434518721` according to https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php So `let timeStamp: Double = 1434518721` lazy var date = { Date.init(WithTimeStampFrom1970:timeStamp)} in pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something like https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ you can convert your date to a timestamp. In your case use `1434518721` and create a `Date` from it:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1434518721) // 2015-06-17 05:25:21
```

Alternatively you can store the string and convert it to a date using a `DateFormatter` but that is more expensive and technically not constant.